# How ANTLR separate tokens

Tags: antlr4

I have a grammar where CHAR is a token. A legal expression for my grammar is
CHAR(2).
The point is that ANTLR seems to get the whole String CHAR(2) as a token, hence giving error as unknown token.
To solve this I have to insert spaces after the token , like CHAR (2) .
So, how can I tell ANTLR to separate tokens ?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question and add the grammar.

Comment: If you learn more about great tools for ANTLR grammar development, https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358-antlr-v4-grammar-plugin you can visually debug your lexer/parser rules.

Answer (score 0):

With the following grammar:

```
expression
    : STRING CHAR LPAREN NUMBER RPAREN
    ;

STRING: 'String';
CHAR: 'CHAR';
NUMBER: [0-9]+;
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
ID: [A-Za-z]+;
WS: [ \t\r\n]+ -> channel(HIDDEN);
```

You can parse your expression in an expecting way.